# Connecting to Ubuntu using Remote Desktop Connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a machine with Ubuntu from a different machine running Windows 7 using the Windows Program *Remote Desktop Connection*.

I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

which worked, except that when I connect from my Windows I can only see the blank desktop background of the remote Ubuntu. The taskbar, icons etc are all missing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, neither RDP nor VNC work satisfactorily with the default 3d (compiz-based) Ubuntu session. For RDP you can specify a different desktop session using the `~/.xsession` file on your remote account, for example if it contains

```
gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

then you will get a 2d (metacity-based) desktop, which will likely work better over RDP. Alternatively you can install the gnome-session-fallback package and then run a gnome-classic session

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
```

In VNC the equivalent session-setting is done via the ~/.vnc/xstartup file. You can check the available desktop sessions on your system using

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions
```